# Poner sección encima de otra

Tags: html, css3

Tengo este código que es de la sección 1:

```
background-image: url(../../assets/images/Fondo-Biografia.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
margin-top: -181px;
margin-left: -1%;
z-index: 10;
```

y esta es la sección 2 el cual es el que quiero que quede debajo de la sección 1:

```
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../../assets/images/Fondo-Enfermeras.png);
background-size: 100%;
```

pero intente con el `z-index`, pero la sección 2 sigue saliendo por encima de la sección 1, ¿hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: tambien agrega el html. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/214170/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Aunque el z-index no es una propiedad difícil de entender, debido a suposiciones falsas puede causar confusión para los desarrolladores principiantes. Esta confusión se produce porque el z-index solo funcionará en un elemento cuya propiedad de posición se haya establecido explícitamente en absoluta, fija o relativa.

Comment: entonces pongo la seccion 1 en posicion relativa?

Comment: Agrega el html amigo, para poder ayudarte :)

Answer (score -1):

Pone reglas relative y absolute con el zindex para la absolute y

Comment: Creo que la respuesta está incompleta. ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo con el css necesario?